# Workflow rule not working with change of Contact.Owner?

Tags: workflowrule

I approached problem which obviously is not solvable by a trigger. I need to update Contacts's field on change on it's owner's field. Not accomplishable in trigger because MIXED_DML_EXCEPTION. Workaround it use future handle, however I have another future handler on Contact, so dead end this way. That's why I need to use workflow rule.

I created a rule which is triggered on object Contact with rule criteria set to `Owner.Active = false`. This does not fire at all. If I set rule criteria to any field on actual Contact, it does fire. If I set rule to any other field on Contact's owner, it does not fire. Do I get it wrong and it is not possible to set rule criteria to object's lookup? Or should that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found out, you can *access* cross-object fields in workflow rules, but cross-object fields cannot *trigger* workflow.

Intuitively, this makes perfect sense. Workflow rules for Object X are triggered when there is a change on Object X. You're updating a field on `User`, not `Contact`. Therefore, workflow rules are not evaluated on `Contact` because *you aren't changing a `Contact`*, you're changing a `User`.

If you don't need the `Contacts` owned by a `User` to be updated immediately, then you might try creating a Schedulable class, and having it run on a schedule [The documentation on the Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) will help with that.

If you do need `Contacts` to be updated immediately, and you're absolutely certain that updating `Contacts` from a `User` trigger causes the mixed DML error, then you really don't have much choice besides going async.

You don't *need* to use an `@future` method. Implementing the Queueable interface ([the documentation on Queueable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) will be helpful there) is one way to work around that issue.

Another way to make it work would be to make your `@future` calls smarter. We can detect if we're in an async context or not. The key here is to not directly call your `@future` method. If you're already in an async context, just call a non-future version of your code. The general pattern for that looks like this...

```java
public class MySmarterFuture{
    // A custom exception class isn't strictly required, but is good practice
    public class MySmarterFutureException extends Exception{}

    public static void run(List<Id> sobjIds){
        try{
            if(system.isFuture() || system.isBatch() || system.isScheduled()){
                system.debug('running async, calling normal run method');
                doNormal(sobjIds);
            } else {
                if (Limits.getFutureCalls() < Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()){
                    system.debug('running future run method');
                    doFuture(sobjIds);
                } else {
                    // Error out
                    throw new MySmarterFutureException('Hit the single transaction @future call limit');
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Caught Exception');
            // Good idea to do some explicit notification here, otherwise the
            //   issues encountered in async contexts are generally silent
        }
    }

    @future
    public static void doFuture(List<Id> sobjIds){
        // No need to duplicate your code, just call the doNormal method!
        // The fact that we're in this block of code at all means that we've
        //   already taken care of getting into an async context.
        doNormal(sobjIds);
    }

    private static doNormal(List<Id> sobjIds){
        // The work that you would normally put in your future method goes in this
        // non-future method instead
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try this

[image]

You must check whether the owner is changed and then add field updated.

Make sure to choose the highlighted radio selection because the formula only works on the selected radio selection in the image.